# Riak inserting Lists

Tags: java, solr, riak, batching

How do I go about inserting a list of maps in Riak? I'd also be able to query list via Solr.

Here is my target data model:

```
{  
   "id":"fa0b758cf8de4a40a54f215563bb483c",
   "version":"g2wAAAABaAJtAAAADN4oTJvAfuENAAE8fWEBag==",
   "creator":"ADMIN",
   "creatorAppId":"RIAK_QA_APP1",
   "creation":1470350862095,
   "customerId":"68af96dae60ccac4e6",
   "customerName":"John Appleseed",
   "orders":[  
      {  
         "orderId":"238dhu38ehj",
         "orderType":"sporting",
         "orderDescription":"Baseball Batt",
         "dateOfPurchase":"5470354262012",
         "delivery":"2 day express",
         "processTimeMS":56,
         "customerAttributes":[  
            {  
               "key":"lastSessionDuration",
               "value":"1 day"
            },
            {  
               "key":"memberSince",
               "value":"1470350862095"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "orderId":"9sdjh349hn",
         "orderType":"furniture",
         "orderDescription":"Sectional Couch",
         "dateOfPurchase":"0970354262087",
         "delivery":"Overnight",
         "processTimeMS":78,
         "customerAttributes":[  
            {  
               "key":"lastSessionDuration",
               "value":"1 day"
            },
            {  
               "key":"memberSince",
               "value":"1470350862095"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "orderId":"1009shdj473",
         "orderType":"gaming",
         "orderDescription":"FIFA 2016 - XBox One",
         "dateOfPurchase":"1470354342013",
         "delivery":"UPS Ground",
         "processTimeMS":68,
         "customerAttributes":[  
            {  
               "key":"lastSessionDuration",
               "value":"1 day"
            },
            {  
               "key":"memberSince",
               "value":"1470350862095"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The current data model persists each order item separately resulting in a high number of Riak writes. This becomes a bottleneck when our messaging system starts pushing through thousands of messages/sec. So the intent here (sort of POC) is to consolidate *all* order items per customer into an `"orders"` list and persists as a single resource..similar to a batch.

On that note, does Riak support any kind of batch insert? I was unable to find a solution so I'm kind of manually doing this by merging the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special to store complex data structures in Riak. The Java client support serialization to JSON (Jackson for that matter, so you can use Jackson capabilities, for example annotations).

I would suggest modeling your data with DTOs and just sending them via the Riak's `StoreValue` command. Code like this will work:

```java
public class CustomerData {
    private String id;
    private String version;
    // other customer fields
    private List<Order> orders;
}

public class Order {
    private String orderId;
    private String orderType;
    // other order fields
}

CustomerData data = ...;
Location location = new Location(new Namespace(BUCKET_TYPE, BUCKET_NAME), key);
StoreValue storeCommand = new StoreValue.Builder(data).withLocation(location).build();
riakClient.execute(storeCommand);
```

Alternatively, you can model this as `Map's` and `List's` of `Object's`.

Keep in mind though, that if you'll want to update, add or delete individual orders, or change customer date, you will have to read an entire list, change an item, and then write the entire list back, potentially increasing the chance of a conflict (concurrent updates to the same key).

Solr definitely supports complex field structures, multi-valued and dynamic fields. Have a look at [Creating Search Schemas](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/developing/usage/search-schemas/). I need to know what part of your data you want searchable to give you an example.

And no, Riak does not support batch insert.

**UPDATE**: A custom (non-generic) Solr schema for indexing by order IDs in your case should include

```xml
<field name="orders.orderId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks. An individual order will never need to be updated. However new order items should be added/added to a customers orders list. I will want to search each order by it's orderId.
I am interested in modeling it as Map's and Lists's of Objects as you mentioned. Can you share some detail on how to model this in Riak?

Comment: It's the same problem. When I wrote "update individual orders" I meant adding and deleting too. Same goes for any piece of information that is part of the structure. Searching by `orderId` is easy - you have to index `orders.orderId` as `string` and make them multi-valued.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to consolidate the data or store the model as separate key-value pairs? For example, each order in a separate unique key and a list of orders in a different key linked to the customer. By `Maps` and `Lists` I meant the Java classes, if for some reason you don't want to create DTO classes to represent your model.

Comment: Yes, I want to consolidate the data. I think your solution using StoreValue will work in my case so I'll give that a try first. I'm just hoping the Jackson de/serializers won't cause performance to tank.

Comment: If you prefer working with JSON as `String` you can do that, too. Riak does not care how you send it, just make sure to set the content type to "application/json" so it's indexed correctly https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/developing/getting-started/java/crud-operations/. But you'll have to construct the JSON anyhow. And I don't think you have better serialization alternatives to JSON.